# How to get Qt icon (QIcon) given a file extension

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, icons

I am developing an application that needs to **display icons associated with different file types**.
Eg for **.doc** extensions, i need it to be able to display the **Microsoft Word icon**.

**QUESTION:**

How can I somehow get a QIcon from the system using QT sdk

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [QtGui.QFileIconProvider](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfileiconprovider.html) class.

Comment: Just little performance tip. If you need to provide those icons very often, create one local instance of QFileIconProvider. Construction of QFileIconProvider is heavy

Comment: It looks like `QFileIconProvider` is expensive to construct because the cache used to not be shared between multiple instances. However, this seems to have changed in [Qt 5.8](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/src/widgets/itemviews/qfileiconprovider.cpp?id=2cd2cba0868efb7e8dd2d00805f1a5ceed0a1349). It now uses the cache of e.g. `QWindowsTheme` which is shared between all instances.

Answer (score 3):

Since Qt5, use QMimeDatabase for that:

```
QMimeDatabase mime_database;

QIcon icon_for_filename(const QString &filename)
{
  QIcon icon;
  QList<QMimeType> mime_types = mime_database.mimeTypesForFileName(filename);
  for (int i=0; i < mime_types.count() && icon.isNull(); i++)
    icon = QIcon::fromTheme(mime_types[i].iconName());

  if (icon.isNull())
    return QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_FileIcon);
  else
    return icon;
}
```

Comment: fromTheme is linux only, isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have special requirement, [`QMimeDatabase`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedatabase.html) is a better choice for your need. I recommend you try @nitro2005's answer. You can still do this work by your hand by using `QFileIconProvider`.

If you want to do this work by your hand but you can't use `QMimeDatabase` for some reason, there is a solution works for  Linux/X11. You can use `QFileInfo(const QString &file)` to get the file's suffix / extension (It's not necessary about the QString you passed to the `QFileInfo` constructor is a exist path or not), and then get the MIME type form that suffix, at last you can get the QIcon by using `QIcon::fromTheme` and it's done.

For example, the following code will check if file's suffix is ".bin", if is, the give it a icon from the system theme with "application-x-executable" MIME type. In fact it's just maintaining a MIME database by your self.

```
QString fileName("example.bin");
QFileInfo fi(fileName);
if (fi.suffix().compare(QString("bin")) == 0) {
    item->setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("application-x-executable",
                                    provider.icon(QFileIconProvider::File)));
}
```

To get the MIME type string reference for your "MIME database", please checkout the [freedesktop icon naming spec](https://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html).