# Use a system icon in the setIcon method of QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, icons

I would like cross-platform a way to get a system icon, for example the folder icon [image: folder icon] in the `setIcon` method of `QWidget`. Something like this:

```
QWidget *myWidget = new QWidget;
myWidget->setIcon(/*something to get a system icon*/);
```

Is this possible? If it is, how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `QFileIconProvider::icon(IconType)` to get an icon of a particular kind, from a small selection of types.

  In your particular case, you'd want `icon(QFileIconProvider::Folder)`.
- Use `QFileIconProvider::icon(const QFileInfo &)` to get an icon for a particular directory entry.
- Use `QIcon::fromTheme(const QString &, const QIcon & = QIcon())` to get a theme icon on Linux/X11.

Comment: You have to create an object of type `QFileIconProvider` to use the `icon` method. Like this: `QFileIconProvider iconProvider; iconProvider.icon(QFileIconProvider::Folder)`.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I didn't say otherwise :) I'm giving fully qualified method names - I don't imply these are static methods, who told ya that :)

Comment: The way you wrote it, it looks like they're supposed to be used as static methods. It would be good to post a code with a concrete example of how to use it. When I first saw this, I thought they were static methods, and I didn't understand they weren't until the compiler gave me an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`QIcon::fromTheme`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme) method.

Example:

```
QIcon undoicon = QIcon::fromTheme("edit-undo");
```

> **Note:** By default, only X11 will support themed icons. In order to use themed icons on Mac and Windows, you will have to bundle a compliant theme in one of your `themeSearchPaths()` and set the appropriate `themeName()`.

Answer (score 0):

For linux/X11, maybe you are looking for [`QMimeDatabase::mimeTypesForFileName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedatabase.html#mimeTypesForFileName) and [`QIcon::fromTheme`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme).

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45739529/5785726 for a example